# Change color of elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This should be easy but I'm not getting it for some reason. How would I set the CSS color style (e.g. color:green) of all the elements who are of class 'foobar' using jQuery?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery and mouseover? why can't you do it with plain CSS? Do you need to change the color when the mouse hovers the elements?

Comment: @JamesBrownIsDead the original title was 'jQuery each onmouseover' which was rather puzzling.

Comment: He edited the question to say on mouseover... I think now we're just stepping on each other :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the color to go green just on mouseover? Can you be more specific?

```
$('.foobar').mouseover( function() {
  $(this).css( { color: 'green' } );
} );
```

Comment: This might not be what @JamesBrownIsDead wanted, the title says something about mouseover. This exact behavior can be achieved without the use of javascript, just CSS

Comment: Could also be expressed as: $(".foobar").css("color", "green");

Comment: @Pablo: True, fleshed it out. Need more info from the asker :)

Comment: @Chase: Of course, that's true. I've been annoyed one too many times by needing to add another css property and having to rewrite the parameters :)

Comment: Seems like you were right since this is the accepted answer. Gonna rephrase the question, and specially the title

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with plain CSS:

```
.foobar {
    background-color:red;
}

.foobar:hover {
    background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: Also he never said he wanted the color going back to what it was before :)